# How do I measure the power of the network (the WIFI signal) in windows-CE?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

How do I measure the power of the network (the WIFI signal) in windows-CE ?

Answer (score 3):

[Building a Wi-Fi Discovery Application with the .NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx) is a nice tutorial on using OpenNETCF to query network adapters - should cover what you need.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it dosnt work on Windows-CE only on Windows-Mobile

Comment: Works fine on Windows CE, provided your adapter is WZC compliant (which is the same requirement for it to work on WinMo).